# Need help on how to get the console output / return values as string

Tags: powershell

I need help on capturing the output messages or return values on console screen, and store them in variable and reuse them later.
I need this to record the result of [XMLA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186604.aspx) execution and error messages, though Powershell errors can be retrieved using $Error[0], I'd like to explore the possibility of capturing what is displayed on the console screen.
I've found Start-Transcript but writing to a txt file does not seems too handy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you run it as a background job, the output to the various data streams will be held in the buffers, and you can access each output stream of the child job individually:

```
$scriptblock = {
 $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
 $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
 Write-Output "This is output"
 Write-Verbose "This is verbose"
 Write-Warning "This is a Warning"
 Write-Debug "This is Debug"
 Write-Error "This is an Error"
}

 $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
 Wait-Job -Job $job
 Receive-Job $job


 $job.ChildJobs[0].Output
 $job.ChildJobs[0].Verbose
 $job.ChildJobs[0].Warning
 $job.ChildJobs[0].Debug
 $job.ChildJobs[0].Error
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting this right, it only shows one BackgroundJob for $job, and Output is empty. I tried to use with `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Username $UserName -Password $Password ` and `$xmlac.Send($query, $properties)` but nothing is captured.

Comment: The background job will have at least one child job.  Use Get-Job -IncludeChildJobs to see the Jobs and their associated child jobs.  The child jobs is where the code actually executes, and that's where the output buffers will be that will contain the data you're after.

Comment: I have tried `$job = (start-job -initializationscript $init -ScriptBlock (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -InputFile $ScriptFileLocation) | wait-job | receive-job -Keep)` but still unable to capture the output, is there an other way for this implementation?

Comment: Have you tried getting the output buffers (e.g. $job.childjobs[0].output) like the example uses?  If you run that example, exactly as posted, do you get the script output twice?

Comment: I've tried adding the Invoke-Sqlcmd into the scriptblock, it is able to show all the process as Verbose and Error. Seems like I hit another issue that the function is not able to carried out properly within the scriptblock.

Comment: That might need to be another question.